# Solr logging with Tomcat: Empty logfiles

Tags: tomcat, logging, solr, tomcat6, sunspot

I'm running Solr 4.2 with Tomcat6 on an Ubuntu 12 machine.
I wanted to setup logging for Solr, because I have some other issues, and I can't figure out. I hope that inside the logfiles, I get all the URLs my applications are sending to Solr.

I followed this guide http://skybert.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/how-to-get-solr-to-log-to-a-log-file/ to enable Solr logging in it's own file. My problem is, that the file is created, but it's empty:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat6 tomcat6     0 Aug 24 11:24 solr.2013-08-24.log
```

For the solr setup, I followed this guide: http://jmuras.com/blog/2012/setup-solr-4-tomcat-ubuntu-server-12-04-lts/

So, any ideas why solr isn't logging into the files? I'm using Solr through a DSL called sunspot with Rails 3. And because I have some issues with sunspot, I want to have a look in the Solr logs, what URLs are really called (and not what the sunspot DSL tells me ;) )

**EDIT**

I found some errors inside the `catalina.out`:

```
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 24, 2013 11:31:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Aug 24, 2013 11:31:36 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/solr] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ThreadLocalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ThreadLocalDateFormat@609e7d46]) and a value of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat@6b2ed43a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 24, 2013 11:31:37 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 24, 2013 11:31:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Aug 24, 2013 11:31:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Aug 24, 2013 11:31:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Aug 24, 2013 11:31:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Aug 24, 2013 11:31:38 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 24, 2013 11:31:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 299 ms
Aug 24, 2013 11:31:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 24, 2013 11:31:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Aug 24, 2013 11:31:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ROOT.xml
Aug 24, 2013 11:31:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor solr.xml
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Aug 24, 2013 11:31:40 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 24, 2013 11:31:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1677 ms
```

But how do I initialize log4j properly? Inside `/var/lib/tomcat6/shared` there are these jars:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat6 tomcat6   4096 Aug 12 10:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root    root      4096 Aug 11 14:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat6 tomcat6   4096 May 23 16:52 classes
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat6 tomcat6  17289 Aug 11 14:35 jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat6 tomcat6   4955 Aug 11 14:35 jul-to-slf4j-1.6.6.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat6 tomcat6 481535 Aug 11 14:35 log4j-1.2.16.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat6 tomcat6  26176 Aug 11 14:35 slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat6 tomcat6   9711 Aug 11 14:35 slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
```

Comment: can show you log file configuration also any errors in the tomcat logs which would indicate the failure to log ?

Comment: Is the Solr logfile not found in $TOMCAT_HOME/bin directory?

Comment: I found some errors, and added some more information